# How to set "403 Forbidden" code response message through axios?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios

I am working with a Token API with using of this JWT [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/) :

It is working well with 200 status code. But how can i handle 403 Forbidden error message ? As how can i set my custom error message when there is status code of `403 Forbidden`?

`loginAction.js` file

```
export const LoginAction = (FormData) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } ,
      url: API,
      data: FormData,
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        localStorage.setItem('tpwToken', response.data.token);
        dispatch({
          type: 'SET_USER',
          user: response.data,
          message: response.data.message
      })
    })
    .catch(function(error){
      console.log(error.message)
    })
  }
}
```

`loginReducer.js`

```
export const loggedUserData = (state = initialState, action = {}) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case "SET_USER":
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: !isEmpty(action.user),
        user: action.user,
        message: action.message
      }

    default: return state  
  }
}

export default loggedUserData;
```

[image: console error message]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Inside your api response...you will check the status from the network call(ajax call) response.

```
.then(function (response) {
    if(response.data.status === 403){
        // throw error or log it
    }
    ...rest of the code
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition to check the status code from the config options. Try something like this.

```
export const LoginAction = (FormData) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } ,
      url: API,
      data: FormData,
      validateStatus: function (status) {
         if(status === 403){
             // do something
          }
       }
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        localStorage.setItem('tpwToken', response.data.token);
        dispatch({
          type: 'SET_USER',
          user: response.data,
          message: response.data.message
      })
    })
    .catch(function(error){
      console.log(error.message)
    })
  }
}
```